# How do you pass in variables that concatenate in MongoDB queries?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, concatenation

The `'cars.$.'+item` concatenation below doesn't work in a MongoDB Query. 
The loop should query `'cars.color'`, `'cars.year'`, `'cars.manufacturer'`
**How do you write it so it loops through properly?**

```js
let car ={
color: 'blue',
year: 2007,
manufacturer: 'Honda'
}  

Object.keys(car).forEach(key => {
  col.updateOne({'cars.$.'+key: car[key]});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need square brackets to build object key dynamically in JS:

```
col.updateOne(query, { $set: {['cars.$.'+key]: car[key]} });
```

Also instead of running `updateOne` in a loop which calls database multiple times you can build one `$set` statement:

```js
let car ={
   color: 'blue',
   year: 2007,
   manufacturer: 'Honda'
}

let set = {};

Object.keys(car).forEach(key => { set['car.' + key] = car[key] });

let update = { $set: set }
console.log(update);
```

More on how to use `$set` [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

Comment: thank you. If I'm updating a database, could you kindly clarify where I would include the collection name in the set[ ] statement, in this case 'col'?

Comment: @wongz you can take a look at the documentation examples: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-top-level-fields